# Writing Avro data to BigQuery

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, google-bigquery

Using `Confluent.Kafka` library, I've created a .NET Kafka consumer, which reads data from a topic and deserializes Avro data to .NET classes.

Now, I'm trying to serialize it back to Avro format and send it to BigQuery. I expect BigQuery to automatically generate table structure based on Avro schema.

I set my consumer deserializer like this(AvroGeneratedDto - .NET class that represents avro schema):

```
            var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<string, AvroGeneratedDto>(
                consumerConfig
            ).SetValueDeserializer(
                    new SyncOverAsyncDeserializer<AvroGeneratedDto>(
                        new AvroDeserializer<AvroGeneratedDto>(_configProvider.SchemaRegistryClient)));
```

It deserializes data into AvroGeneratedDto OK.

Now, I try to serialize it back using schema stored in schema registry:

```
var serializer = new AvroSerializer<AvroGeneratedDto>(_configProvider.SchemaRegistryClient);
var avroSerialized = await serializer.SerializeAsync(item.Value, new SerializationContext(MessageComponentType.Value, topic: "MyTopic"));
```

And upload it to BigQuery:

```
                    MemoryStream avroStream = new MemoryStream(avroSerialized);
                    var job = await _bigQueryClient.UploadAvroAsync(projectId: projectId, datasetId: ArtsdatasetId, tableId: TableId, schema: null, input: avroStream, options: options);
```

However, I get the following from BigQuery:

> "*Error while reading data, error message: The Apache Avro library failed to parse the header with the following error: Invalid data file. Magic does not match*".

What is the issue here?

Comment: Why aren't you using Kafka Connect?

Comment: Are you refering to https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/connectors/cc-gcp-bigquery-sink.html ?
This does not support automatic schema creation

Comment: You mean in bigquery? I think it does support it if the Avro data changes

Comment: @cricket_007. No, this connector uses autoUpdateSchemas=false
bigQueryMessageTimePartitioning=false and I there's no way to change it from UI at least.

Comment: Can you please link to that config settings? Kafka Connect doesn't have a UI, by the way

Comment: @Aurimas, This error you are getting, it is generally related to load a file which is not in **.avro** format. Are you sure that your data is serialized back to avro format within your code? In addition, I would like to point that BigQuery supports loading [Avro files] (http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.0/spec.html#Object+Container+Files), but it does not have any formal definition of .avro schema, thus it is not supported. In case you want to create an empty table in BigQuery, you can use [BigQuery Json schema file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#specifying_a_json_schema_file).

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, you may be right - serializer.SerializeAsync(..) does not seem to generate a normal .avro file, if I create a file out of this serializer result. Is there something wrong with my serialization?

I tried importing an example twitter .avro file from: https://github.com/miguno/avro-cli-examples/blob/master/twitter.avro - BigQuery succesfully generates table schema for me.

Comment: @Aurimas, I believe there might be something wrong with your serialization. I was investigating your code, I could find some differences based on this [sample](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroGeneric/Program.cs), have a look in the deserialization ( **new ConsumerBuilder**...) and in **AvroSerializer**. Also I noticed that it is missing a parenthesis in the **SerializeAsync** method.

Comment: Continuing, I also checked the documentation (for **SerializeAsync**) and apparently it is used correctly, have a look [here](https://engineering.chrobinson.com/dotnet-avro/api/chr.avro.confluent.asyncschemaregistryserializer-1.serializeasync).

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, missing paranthesis was essentialy a copy - paste mistake, fixed it. 
Also, tried the example with GenericRecord instead of my "AvroGeneratedDto". Getting the same error.

Comment: I found this [document](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AvroBlogExamples/Program.cs) starting at the line 34, where you can check another way on how to use generic record. Furthermore, is your SchemaRegistryClient correct ? This [page](https://www.confluent.io/blog/decoupling-systems-with-apache-kafka-schema-registry-and-avro/) explains serialization and deserialization with .NET. I could notice some differences from your code, can you check that?